# Additional arguments have no effect on Azure DevOps Resharper Code Quality Analysis

Tags: .net, yaml, azure-pipelines, resharper, azure-pipelines-yaml

```
- task: ResharperCli@2
  displayName: Automated Code Quality Scan (Warn)
  condition: eq('${{ parameters.Action }}', 'Warn')
  inputs:
    SolutionOrProjectPath: $(Services_SolutionPath)
    failBuildLevelSelector: Warning
    failBuildOnCodeIssues: ${{ parameters.ShouldFailBuild }}
    additionalArguments: /disable-settings-layers:SolutionPersonal --no-build
    reSharperNuGetVersion: Latest
```

This is my yaml task, but looks like the additional arguments are coming in double quotes (like below output) and CLI is ignoring them. I believe the additional arguments should come with out quotes to make it work.

```
Invoking InspectCode.exe using arguments "D:\a\1\s\BC-Test\Service\Upmc.Test.sln" /o:"D:\a\1\a\JetBrains.ReSharper.CommandLineTools.2021.2.0\tools\Reports\CodeInspection_Unlabeled_Build.xml" "/disable-settings-layers:SolutionPersonal --no-build"
```

I was trying to do no build, but those parameters are completely ignored and it did run the build.

Did any one face this issue?

Comment: Please try add single quote `additionalArguments: '/disable-settings-layers:SolutionPersonal --no-build'`

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I tried that and it produce same results, also tried changing orders with no affect.

Answer (score 1):

Update this didn't work when I tried it.

<del>It looks like this issue was introduced in version 2. You can work around this for now by using version 1.</del>

[image: Task Version]

There is an issue raised on GitHub, see link below.

https://github.com/alanwales/vsts-resharper-code-quality-task/issues/26